# How to execute a task in another function only after N seconds n Python?

Tags: python

Here is the function structure

```
def my_main():
    ...... 
    function_a()
    function_b()
    ....

def function_a():
    ....
    time_diff = datetime.datetime.now() - last_execution_time 
    if time_diff.seconds > N:
        task_a
        last_execution_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

my_main keeps continuously running and if certain condition satisfies it triggers `task_a` in `function_a`. I want to execute `task_a` say only after N seconds of its previous execution, if it triggers before N seconds, it should silently pass.

The basic logic is to maintain a constant that keeps measuring the time when task_a was previously executed, but due to scope issue, when execution shifts to main, the variable last_execution_time loses its value, additionally how do you initialise it for the first time?

Comment: You could declare the variable in the main loop and pass it as an argument to ```function_a()```. If you needed to keep track of more than one time, you could manage it with a dictionary. There might be other solutions, but that should work.

Comment: when you declare the variable in the main loop, how do you initialise it for the first time. say inside main `function_a(last_executed_time, ....)` how do you get the last_executed_time for the first time, how do you keep updating that value.

Comment: You could initialize it as ```None``` or an arbitrary start time well in the past. Then you pass ```last_execution_time``` as an argument into ```function_a()```. Then you update that variable within the function exactly as you do now. Then, return ```last_execution_time``` and assign it back. So, within the main loop, it looks like this: ```last_execution_time = function_a(last_execution_time )```. It's probably not the most pythonic solution, but it's a solution.

Comment: You could wrap the functions to member functions of a class. The `last_execution_time` variable thus can be saved as a member attribute.